# Creating inset shadow within scrollable region but above internal divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `paper-dialog-scrollable` of which I would like a shadow to appear at the top when scrolling down the page.

However, if I set an `inset` box shadow, any internal `div`s simply go over the top of it even after playing with `z-index`.

Can anybody help me? Please see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3o7g0oz/) to play/edit.

The aim is to have no shadow when content hasn't been scrolled, then fade in when it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make one more class `boxShadow` to define `box-shadow` on scrolling div.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index:-1;
}
.boxShadow{box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); width:400px; height:20px; background:#e5e5e5;}
```

```html
<div class="boxShadow"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative `z-index` and `position: relative` on the  `.content` to move it under the `.container`, and add a `.wrapper` with the background color, `position: relative`, and a positive `z-index` value to provide background under the `.content`.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var containerClasses = container.classList;
container.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if(e.target.scrollTop > 0) {
    containerClasses.contains('shadow') || containerClasses.add('shadow');
  } else {
    containerClasses.remove('shadow');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need the `.content` to be clickable you can add a wrapper with a pseudo element overlay. The overlay has `pointer-events: none`, which means that the content under it can be clicked. The only problem is the width of the scrollbar, which is not consistent across browsers:

```js
var wrapperClasses = document.querySelector('.wrapper').classList;
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if(e.target.scrollTop > 0) {
    wrapperClasses.contains('shadow') || wrapperClasses.add('shadow');
  } else {
    wrapperClasses.remove('shadow');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.wrapper::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 12px); /** the width minus the scrollbar width **/
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  content: "";
}

.shadow::before {
  opacity: 1;
}


.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this solution, any clickable element (e.g. `a`, `button`) in `.content` won't clickable anymore.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey - it's for display purposes only.

Comment: Any clues on if I actually want my website to have any sort of functionality then @OriDrori? :-P

Comment: @physicsboy - added another solution, which enables clicks. However, because of the inconsistencies in scrollbar width across browsers might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OriDrori. Seems strange that there isn't an easier way to do this. Now I just have to figure out how to toggle this when I actually scroll XD

Comment: @physicsboy - there might be another way :) You can use vishnu's code to show/hide the shadow, and if you use JS, you can also calculate the width of the scrollbar on the way.

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen @Vishnu's answer. Looks like you two should colab. ;-)
I'll give it a go, and see if I can find out how to calculate things haha. So far I've been using the calc(100vh - so many px) in other pages, so we will see!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149793/discussion-between-physicsboy-and-ori-drori).

Comment: @OriDrori, any chance you could help me out with retrofitting Vishnu's code to yours? I'm really wanting to avoid using JQuery and use an on-scroll

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JQuery:

```js
var header = $(".container");
 $(".container").scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 2) {
            $(this).addClass("shadow");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("shadow");
        }
 });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.container.shadow {
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the transition input @Vishnu, however my main problem is that the blue div is still on top of the shadow rather than underneath (with functioning buttons etc)